# Methods to discourage reverse engineering of an opencl kernel

Tags: opencl

I am preparing my opencl accelerated toolkit for release. Currently, I compile my opencl kernels into binaries targeted for a particular card.

Are there other ways of discouraging reverse engineering? Right now, I have many opencl binaries in my release folder, one for each kernel. Would it be better to splice these binaries into one single binary, or even add them into the host binary, and somehow read them in using a special offset ?

Comment: You could encode them into a file then decode using a key(maybe connects to server to get it?) and algorithm.

Comment: Good idea. Re-enter this as an answer and I will mark correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode binaries. Keep keys in server and have clients request it at time of usage. Ofcourse keys should be encoded too,( using a variable value such as time of server maybe). Then decode in client to use as binary kernel.

I'm not encode pro but I would use multiple algorithms applied multiple times to make it harder, if they are crunchable in several months(needed for new version update of your GPGPU software for example) when they are alone. But simple unknown algorithm of your own such as reversing order of bits of all data (1st bit goes nth position, nth goes 1st) should make it look hard for level-1 hackers.

Warning: some profiling tools could get its codes in "run-time" so you should add many maybe hundreds of trivial kernels without performance penalty to hide it in a crowded timeline or you could disable profiling in kernel options or you could add a deliberate error maybe some broken events in queues then restart so profiler cannot initiate.

Maybe you could obfuscate final C99 code so it becomes unreadable by humans. If can, he/she doesn't need hacking in first place.

Maybe most effectively, don't do anything, just buy copyrights of your genuine algorithm and show it in a txt so they can look but can not dare copying for money.

If kernel can be rewritten into an "interpreted" version without performance penalty, you can get bytecodes from server to client, so when client person checks profiler, he/she sees only interpreter codes but not real working algorithm since it depends on bytecodes from server as being "data"(buffer). For example, c=a+b becomes if(..)else if(...)else(case ...) and has no meaning without a data feed.

On top of all these, you could buy time against some evil people reverseengineer it, you could pick variable names to initiate his/her "selective perception" so he/she can't focus for a while. Then you develop a meaner version at the same time. Such as c=a+b becomes bulletsToDevilsEar=breakDevilsLeg+goodGame

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL 2.0 and SPIR-V can be used for this, but is not available on all platforms yet.

Comment: what is harder to decompile: binary or SPIR-V ?

Comment: I'm assuming binary, but check your particular vendor's binary -- some also include higher-level encodings as well as device binaries. Long ago one vendor included your source too!

Comment: Thanks, @Dithermaster. I am stripping out intermediate representations and source from binary.